# JQuery-ui Tabs - reload page with completely new content not working

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I'm loading in a report and displaying it with jquery-ui in tab format. The report is returned by an ajax call in json, and a function is formatting it into HTML. Example code below:

```
<div id="reportdiv">
</div>

<script>
function displayreport(objectid)
{
    $( "#reportdiv" ).hide();
    $( "#reportdiv" ).html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        headers: { 'authtoken': getToken() },
        url:'/reportservice/v1/report/'+objectid.id,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == null)
            {
                alert("That report does not exist.");
            }
            else
            {
                var retHTML = dataToTabHTML(data.config);
                $("#reportdiv").html(retHTML).fadeIn(500);
                $(function() {
                    tabs = $( "#reportdiv" ).tabs();
                    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
                      axis: "x",
                      stop: function() {
                        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
                      }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

This works fine the first time displayreport is called. However, if the user enters another value and runs displayreport again, the "tabs" format is completely lost (the tabs are displayed as links above my sections, and clicking on a link takes you to that section further down the page).

I figured completely re-setting the reportdiv html at the beginning of the function would bring me back to original state and allow it to work normally every time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle to demonstrate. Click the reload button the first time, it works. Click it the second time, it has the problem I describe. Ideas? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/scmxyras/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing, found that destroy was the way to go. If I've set up tabs already, run the destroy, otherwise, skip the destroy (http://jsfiddle.net/scmxyras/1/) :

```
if(tabs!=undefined)$( "#reportdiv" ).tabs("destroy");
```